# How can I set the custom brightness adjusment in (JavaCameraView) CameraBridgeViewBase?

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I want to implement brightness adjustment in an app that uses that uses OpenCV camera. I have found methods and I have found in the documentation of `JavaCameraView` and `CameraViewBridge` Base if exists some method to do it directly but I have not found.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps that will help you adjust the exposure of the camera 
First create a CustomCameraView java class

```
public class CustomCameraView extends JavaCameraView implements Camera.PictureCallback {
private String mPictureFileName;

public CustomCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public List<String> getEffectList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
}

public boolean isEffectSupported() {
    return (mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null);
}

public String getEffect() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode();
}

public void setEffect(String effect) {
    mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(effect);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

// set Camera Exposure value from input progress (0.0f - 1.0f)
public void setExposure(float progress) {
    if (progress < 0.0f && progress > 1.0f) return;
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    int min = params.getMinExposureCompensation();
    int max = params.getMaxExposureCompensation();
    float realProgress = progress - 0.5f;
    int value;
    if (realProgress < 0) {
        value = -(int) (realProgress * 2 * min);
    } else {
        value = (int) (realProgress * 2 * max);
    }
    // if changed
    if (value != params.getExposureCompensation()) {
        params.setExposureCompensation(value);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
}

public void setPreviewFPS(double min, double max) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setPreviewFpsRange((int) (min * 1000), (int) (max * 1000));
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public List<Camera.Size> getResolutionList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
}

public void setResolution(int w, int h) {
    disconnectCamera();
    mMaxHeight = h;
    mMaxWidth = w;
    connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Camera.Size getResolution() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
    this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
    // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
    // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

    // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }

}

public void cameraRelease() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
}
```

After that in the layout file of the activity where you declared the `JavaCameraView` , change that with this

```
<your.package.CustomCameraView
    android:id="@+id/cameraViewer"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    opencv:show_fps="false" />
```

NOTE:change `your.package` with the appropriate package name

Finally in the activity add this

```
cameraBridgeViewBase = (CustomCameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraViewer);
cameraBridgeViewBase.setExposure(1.0f);
```

NOTE: change this value `1.0f` to your desired value.

I hope this helps you.